# PDF printer software to print website to pdf with hyperlinks

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, offline, printing

Is there a PDF printer software that have the following features:

- Free (do not need to register)
- Offline (do not require to go to internet)
- Is a kind of PDF printer software (e.g. [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp), [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/))
- (**Very important**) Print website to PDF and retain the links. (the pdf file should contain working and clickable links that the website have)
- Windows operating system

Currently, I tried CutePDF and PDFCreator but could not get it to print pdf file that contain working and clickable links that the website have.

Comment: You might want to add: it would be great if it could also print free money ;-)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/809627/print-webpage-to-pdf-with-working-hyperlinks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try WKHTMLTOPDF (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

It is free and lightweight.
The downside is; you have to use it from a CLI. But if you do not want to delve into advanced options like javascript delays, debug outputs etc, it's pretty straightforward to use.
e.g

*wkhtmltopdf.exe [site-to-download] [filename.pdf]*

Answer (score 1):

1. **[HTMLDOC](http://www.msweet.org/documentation/project1/HTMLDOC.html)** can do this. It is Free Software.
2. **[PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/)** can also do it. PrinceXML is very powerful, supporting most of the CSS2 standard for styling the PDF output. It isn't Open Source, but gratis to use for private use.
3. **[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)** is my third recommendation. It is Free Software, the "swiss army knife" of document and format conversions. Though its main strength lays in processing *Markdown* input, it can also consume HTML. For PDF output, it requires a working LaTeX installation. In this case its version 1.13.2 can create a PDF output with this command:

   ```
   pandoc -f html                  \
          -V geometry:margin=1.5cm \
          -o pandoc.pdf            \
             http://pandoc.org/
   ```

   Here is a screenshot of the resulting PDF:

   [image]